# Can we instruct PAServer to execute custom commands?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

When I finished deploying my app (in release), I would like to automatically send it to the app store. For this I need to run this simple command:

```
./altool — upload-app -f {abs path to your project}.ipa -u {apple id to publish the app} -p {password of apple id}
```

Is their a way to instruct PAServer (delphi RIO/Sydney) to run this command at the end of the deployment?

Comment: No - it can only run commands that it "knows" about. If my Mosco app doesn't do what you want (hint: it shows the full command executed in the messages window), let me know and I'll take a look at modifying it.

Comment: @DaveNottage In fact my problem is not about uploading the ipa, but more about signing some framework (https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22899)

Comment: Then your question should be about that? Codesigning was changed to use the --deep option, so the frameworks should be being signed anyway. Do they need to be codesigned separately for some reason?

Comment: @DaveNottage hmm I was not aware of the --deep option :) is this in Rio or un Sydney ?

Comment: In 10.3.3, I believe.